# Can a juror's vote count as the opposite of their actual vote if they explicitly state they vote against their opinion?

Tags: united-states, jury, criminal-procedure, process, jury-nullification

Suppose there is a hypothetical situation in which a person on a jury becomes infatuated with a criminal defendant.  Suppose they make this explicitly clear during jury deliberations.  For example, let's say it's a male juror and he says "she is too hot to go to jail even though she is clearly guilty, so I am voting 'not guilty.'"

Let's say the same juror persistently keeps voting "no" when the jury tries to decide if they should convict or not.  Is there a process for the juror's opinion, that "she is clearly guilty," to be counted as the opinion they expressed, instead of their vote?

I've never served on a jury, so I don't know.  Maybe it's more appropriate to ask if there is even a vote?  Or do the jurors only need to express their opinion (of guilt/innocence) during the deliberations?

Answer (score 6):

When the required number of jurors vote "yes" (or "no", or whatever the question is), then the jury has reached a verdict. There is no provision whereby the presiding juror can re-interpret "yes" as "no". In the case you describe, if a unanimous verdict is required that despite a reasonable inference that the last juror believes the defendant to be guilty, he has voted not guilty so the jury has not reached a verdict.

In case the guy in charge decides "In this case no means yes", thus falsely presents a supposed unanimous verdict, there is still an option for juror polling, in which case the not-guilty juror gets a chance to affirm his not guilty vote; though one of the parties has to request jury polling. If during polling the juror's response is not a clear "yes", then it could be more complicated.

Comment: note that during polling, Jurors may say exactly one word from two options: Yes or No. Anything else is generally not accepted, at best allowing honorary additions (your honor)